# Umbraco 7 distinguish content/items from eachother

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

So I have two pages: `frontpage.cshtml` and `news.cshtml`. My frontpage contains a list of "services" and a list of "news". When I want to distinguish between which ones I pull out, I do this:

```
var selection = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible");
foreach(var item in selection) {
    if(item.ContentType.Alias == "listNews") {
        //I am dealing with news content/a news item
    }
}
```

I have to do this, since all of my contents/items are located under the same content "type", as you can see here:

[image]

This is extremely bad practise, as I pull out ALL of the items/all content I have, even though I don't need them. ¨

Here is the weird part: I do the exact same piece of code no matter which page I am on. Even if I am on the `news.cshtml` page, it will still pull out the services. How do I separate them so the news page has news, service page has services, and my frontpage can use both of them?

Comment: It sounds like you are using alt templates on your root "Landing Page" node. Is that correct? Or do you have separate root pages that need to list the children of the "Landing Page"? I'm trying to get a better picture of exactly what's going on here. I recommended a quick solution below, but it might be that something architectural could be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big question. The really quick answer is that you can write something like the following. You can pass the documentType alias of the document type you want to filter by.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var child in CurrentPage.Children("GeneralPage"))
    {
        <li>@child.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Another option that I like a lot is to use the UmbracoHelper to help you query for the content you want by XPath. Because the content is cached in an xml structure, querying by XPath is very quick and a pretty normal thing to do.

```
@{
    var news = Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath("/root/LandingPage/NewsItem");
    var services = Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath("/root/LandingPage/Service");
}

<h2>News</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var newsItem in news)
    {
        <li>@newsItem.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

<h2>Services</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var serviceItem in services)
    {
        <li>@serviceItem.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

There are more complex solutions involving [RenderMvcControllers and route hijacking](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers). If you are looking for something more complex and don't like the idea of doing all of this work in your views, you could create some controllers to handle requests to the specific document types. In those controllers, you could handle all of the filtering of collections and querying of umbraco. Then you can forward on the data that you care about to your views. I know you were saying that part of your problem is that your parent node has the mixed bag of types underneath it, so maybe this won't help with your problem. It is nice to know that the RenderMvcControllers exist either way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was really looking for a better way to do this, but this solution seems to do the same thing essentially. I realised I could create a new content page (like for my news) and place them all in there, then I can do `var news = Umbraco.Content(ID_OF_PAGE).Children` for example. I realise I have to hard code the ID, but if I have to hard code the ID or name of the content.. it doesn't really matter that much. This way I can organize my items very, very easily. What do you think?

Comment: One good way to get around hard coding ids is to create a "Site Settings" area of your site and to put a couple of content pickers on it called "News Folder" and "Services Folder".

Comment: That's true! But I assume that once I have created the "folder" they are never going to change ID anyway.

Comment: It depends on the site. It is just something to consider. Having lots of hard coded ids can make maintenance and extending the site more tricky if the site gets big enough. What if some day, you want to use UmbracoCloud or just Courier by itself? If you want to do any sort of importing/exporting or content deployment your sites will likely have different ids for the same, corresponding node. Not hard coding node ids is sort of a best practice thing and you have to decide on a situational basis if following that best practice makes sense and is worth it. On any large project, I'd recommend it.